# Where in the IntelliJ preferences/settings do I specify a JVM?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jvm, version, user-preferences

On macOS, we can add another JVM while having old versions of the JVM still installed.

How do I point IntelliJ 2017.2 to another version of my JVM?

I can find no such setting in the `Preferences` window.

`Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` – Nope.

`Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` – Nope.

`Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler` – Nope.

Comment: ```File``` > ```Project Structure``` > ```Project```

Comment: @izsl  But I do not yet have a project created. Does IntelliJ have its own internally bundled JVM to launch itself?

Comment: If you don't have a project, you can access this dialog from the Welcome Screen: Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs. IDE will ask for it anyway when you will add a new project, so there is not much sense in defining it beforehand.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Can you make that an Answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a project, you can access the dialog with SDK configuration from the **Welcome Screen**: `Configure` | `Project Defaults` | `Project Structure` | **SDKs**.

However, IDE will ask for the SDK anyway when you add a new project, so there is not much sense in defining it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

mac os shortcut is "Command+,"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for Mac. However, since IntelliJ is platform independant, I guess it will be in the same location.
Go to File > Other settings > default project structure for a global change or File > Project Structure for a project dependant change.
Under project SDK you can find the SDK in use, with the New button you can choose another one.
Default will be the newest version if you have not yet a project created.

On the welcome screen before creating a project you can go to Configure at the bottom, Project Default > Project Structure to define the default JDK you want to use. Then hit the new button to choose a not listed JDK and locate it yourself.

Comment: I have not yet created a project.

Comment: Just create one, it will default to the latest JDK. If you want to change that you can do later after the project creation. Edited my answer to provide what you need if you want to change before the creation.